# Express can't find Webpack bundle

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, webpack-dev-server

So I've been configuring a MERN app with a main package that runs an Express server, and a client folder which contains the React front end and has its own package.  To test the client I've been using webpack-dev-server to run an HTML file within the `client/public` folder that links a Webpack bundle in a `dist` folder.  The HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>React Config</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script src="../dist/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The relative path for the bundle is correct, and it works fine using WDS.  However, when I try to serve this file via my Express server, I get a 404 error for the bundle file.  In my server.js:

```
app.use(express.static('client'));

const appPage = path.join(__dirname, './client/public/index.html');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(appPage);
});
```

This does serve the HTML file correctly, but when I navigate to the local server it's trying to find `bundle.js` at `http://localhost:3000/dist/bundle.js`, instead of `http://localhost:3000/client/dist/bundle.js`.  Furthermore, even when I change the path in the HTML to point to the right location, it 404's anyway.

So 2 questions:

1) How can I configure the paths for the Webpack bundle to be accessible both from WDS run within the client folder and from my Express server in the main package?

2) Why is the bundle not being found by Express even when I alter the path to be correct?  I've included the entire client folder as static for the server.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use **webpack-dev-server** for production, **webpack-dev-server** not build the index.html file, **webpack-dev-server** is only for developers.

You can use this command to build it:

```
webpack --config ./webpack.prod.js --mode production
```

Comment: Yes, I am using WDS to develop the client, but I also want to make sure the server itself will be able to serve the HTML file.  What I'm mostly confused about is why the server is unable to locate the webpack bundle no matter what path I give it.  From what I understand, designating the client folder as static should give it access to everything within that folder, including the bundle, but it doesn't seem to work.